# Updating Displayed Text Elements After Dynamically Changing CSS Class With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am coloring each user's text submissions to my application based on a color they choose. To do this, I dynamically add rules to a stylesheet as new users choose their color.

The problem I'm trying to solve is updating this color using AJAX without reloading the page.

I apply the color by assigning a class that corresponds to each user and the story they are submitting to:

```
<span class="<%= "contrib-u#{snippet.user.id}-s#{@story.id}" %>">
  (code to display text submission)
</span>
```

I create classes for each user that match this `contrib-u1-s2` format (contribution for user 1, story 2) using JQuery once when the application loads:

```
$(document).one 'turbolinks:load', ->                                               
  build_contribution_styles()                                                       

build_contribution_styles = ->                                                      
  req = $.get('/contributions/index')                                               

  req.done (data) ->                                                                
    user_sheet = document.styleSheets[5]                                            

    for contribution in data                                                        
      user_sheet.addRule(                                                           
        ".contrib-u" + contribution['user_id'] + "-s" + contribution['story_id'], 
        "color: #" + contribution['color']                                          
      )
```

So far, this works great. Each user's submission for each story is correctly colored based on these dynamically created classes.

Next, I provide the user a text field so they can select a new color for their submissions:

```
<%= text_field_tag :snippet_color,
  current_user.get_contribution_color(@story),
  class: "jscolor centered-text",
  data: {user_id: current_user.id, story_id: @story.id}
%>
```

Then, in JQuery, I attach an event listener to this text field to update the database and the classes with the newly selected color:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->                                                                                         
  $('#snippet_color').change (e) -> handle_snippet_color_change(e, @)                                                                                                                              

handle_snippet_color_change = (e, input) ->                                         
  data = {                                                                          
    contribution: {                                                                 
      story_id: $(input).data('story-id'),                                          
      user_id: $(input).data('user-id'),                                            
      color: $(input).val()                                                         
    }                                                                               
  }                                                                                 

  req = $.post('/contributions/update', data)                                       

  req.done (data) ->                                                                
    els = $('.contrib-u' + data['user_id'] + '-s' + data['story_id'])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    els.css('color', data['color'])
```

This also works nicely, but *only* after I reload the page. The updates to the class are not applied to the elements until then.

This is somewhat confusing to me, because there are a number of other cases where I change the CSS style of an element dynamically with javascript and it changes without any page refresh. For instance, many times in this application I select an element and toggle its display property to hide it or show it.

I've found a few sources of information about "reloading a CSS style without a page refresh", but none of them seem to correct this particular problem. One suggestion was to place these new CSS rules into a style tag on the page with these elements to get them to automatically updated without a reload, but that does not appear to make any difference in my case.

**EDIT: Working Solution**

I have it working now by removing the previous rule and adding an updated rule to the stylesheet:

```
req = $.post('/contributions/update', data)

req.done (data) ->                                                                      
  selector = '.contrib-u' + data['user_id'] + '-s' + data['story_id']          
  sheet = document.styleSheets[5]                                              
  rules = sheet.cssRules                                                       

  for i in [0...rules.length]                                                  
    if rules[i].selectorText is selector                                       
      sheet.deleteRule(i)                                                      
      sheet.addRule(selector, "color: #" + data['color'])
```

The problem was that I was just updating the styles for the existing elements. I'm still not sure why their updated styles were not applied immediately, but this new approach achieves the desired functionality.

Comment: I don't see you updating the style rule you created, only the styles of the elements `els` holds. This will not make new future entries use that a new style.

Comment: does your jQuery callback `req.done` evaluates correctly?

Comment: @Patrick, I was thinking that might be the problem. Maybe the two situations are ambiguous, but everything I could find about "changing a css class with javascript" simply said to grab the class with a selector and then use the `css` method.

I couldn't find a method like `addRule` for actually updating the rule directly. I could try deleting the rule and replacing it with another `addRule`.

Comment: css() simply changes the element's own `style` property and not the rule. So yes creating a new one and removing the old one is a way to go.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, that worked perfectly.